# python/django logging with decorators

Tags: python, django, logging, wrapper

I want to place a decorator on every function to log everything happening in the function. i have made a wrapper function and decorator to log the function with decorator.

**views.py**

```
def func_detail(func):
   @wraps(func)
     def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         r = func(*args, **kwargs)
         logging.getLogger(__name__)
         logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', filemode='a',
                             format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                              level=logging.DEBUG)
         return r
     return func_wrapper

class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @func_detail
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Mytable.objects.all()
        if request.GET.get('name'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(name=request.GET.get('name'))
        serializer = CheckSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        logging.info("GET request and returned response")
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem is log file is not created in this code. Also, it got created on a different project but didnot print anything in log file(empty log file). I want to print a message in log file for everything that is happening, but this doesn't seem to work. Plz help.

Comment: Please start by formatting and correctly indenting your code.

Comment: I did. Thanks for letting me know. @Shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorator inner function should return outer function with args and kwargs and your decorator problem will solve but another problem is Django can't able to stdr the console output of this decorated view function.

```
def func_detail(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logging.getLogger(__name__)
        ----
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func_wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to also track the changes or modification that happen to model along with whatever has been changed to what.. I am using audit_log but it doesn't really help.

Comment: I suggest to use Django logger for model and everything about logging...

Comment: Thanks, will see that and let you know!